# passthrough variable to nested component

Tags: angular

There must be a more elegant way of doing this.

I'm simply; passing this boolean flag from the page markup through to the subcomponent:

```
<span *ngIf="flushToText">
    <span 
        class="icon flushToText" 
        [title]="tooltip" >
    </span> 
</span>
<span *ngIf="!flushToText">
    <span 
        class="icon" 
        [title]="tooltip">
    </span> 
</span>
```

Essentially, this says:
if flushToText is TRUE, then add class flushToText.

(Here's the markup that invokes it:)

```
    <app-td-label 
            id="industry" 
            tooltip="Enter key words" 
            bold="true"
            flushToText="true">
    </app-td-label>
```

I tried ng-class, but I could not seem to get the right syntax. I tried every combination of quotes and brackets:

```
        ng-class="flushToText: flushToText"
        ng-class="'flushToText': flushToText"
        ng-class="{'flushToText': flushToText==true}"
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation. The `ng-class` is an AngularJS(1.x) syntax and won't be applicable to Angular(2+).

The syntax in Angular has changed to:

```
<span 
  class="icon"
  [class.flushToText]="flushToText">
  {{ tooltip }}
</span>
```

Alternatively, you could also use this:

```
<span 
  class="icon"
  [ngClass]="{ 'flushToText': flushToText }">
  {{ tooltip }}
</span>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-class-syntax-eg?file=src/app/td-label/td-label.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks. The second one is what I see it as the more 'standard' method.

Answer (score 0):

To access class variable you need to property binding syntax of Angular

```
[class.class-name] = "classVariableName"
```

So in your case bind like below

```
[class.flushToText] = "flushToText"
```